# Custom clang static analyzer checkers in clang-8

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying to write a custom analyzer in clang using the example given below :

https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html

in the above tutorial, it specifies to add the following in checkers.td:

```
let ParentPackage = UnixAlpha in {
...
def SimpleFunc : Checker<"SimpleFunc">,
  HelpText<"Check for misuses of stream APIs">,
  DescFile<"SimpleFunc.cpp">;
...
} // end "alpha.unix"
```

I've done so and I tried to build clang again but unfortunately, it returns an error as "Class not found DescFile"

So I look around in checkers.td myself none of the other checkers have a DescFile specified they have what is called a Documentation (Version issue maybe?)

so I changed it to Documentation with the value HasAlphaDocumentation and tried to build again but
now it fails to build and returns undefined reference to clang::ento::registerSimpleFunc(CheckerManager &)

below is what my SimpleFunc.cpp file looks like:

```
#include "ClangSACheckers.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/BuiltinCheckerRegistration.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/BugReporter/BugType.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/Checker.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/CheckerManager.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CallEvent.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CheckerContext.h"

using namespace clang ;
using namespace ento ;

namespace {
class SimpleFunc : public Checker < check :: PreCall > {
mutable std :: unique_ptr < BugType > BT ;

public :
void checkPreCall ( const CallEvent & Call , CheckerContext & C ) const ;
};
}

void SimpleFunc :: checkPreCall ( const CallEvent & Call ,
 CheckerContext & C ) const {
if ( const IdentifierInfo * II = Call . getCalleeIdentifier ())
if ( II - > isStr (" main ")) {
if (! BT )
BT . reset (new BugType (this , " Call to main ", " Example checker " ));
ExplodedNode *N = C . generateErrorNode ();
auto Report = llvm :: make_unique < BugReport >(* BT , BT - > getName () , N );
    C.emitReport ( std :: move ( Report ));
 }
 }
void ento :: registerSimpleFunc (CheckerManager & Mgr ) {
    Mgr.registerChecker<SimpleFunc>();
 }
```

Comment: `undefined reference to clang::ento::registerSimpleFunc(CheckerManager &)` is a *linker* error, not a *compiler* error. You are not linking with whatever defines that symbol (or not doing so correctly - link *order* matters on some platforms / with some linkers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I fixed it I forgot to add my file in the Cmakelist.